# Reducing the offset voltage of a source follower

Tags: vlsi, source, cadence, mixed-signal, source-follower

I am currently trying to reduce the offset voltage of the circuit attached below to less than +/- 2mV over a 1V to 4V input range.

I have a few constraints for this task:

- I can use `nmos`, `pmos` and `pmos4` but can't use `nmos4` as the fabrication process does not support separate bulks for NMOS transistors.
- I cannot use controlled sources e.g (`vcvs`,`vccs`,`ccvs`,`cccs`) except when calculating Voffset
- I can only use one `Vdc` for `Vdd` and one `Vdc` for `Vin` and use only `idc` for biasing
- Use at least **100nA** bias current in all transistors

So far I have tried adding cascodes to the circuit to reduce this offset voltage but no luck. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction regarding this task. Thank you.

---

Voltage Follower Circuit:

[image: VOLTAGE FOLLOWER CIRCUIT]